# Url contains improper value

Tags: django

How would I pass the relative url from the page I came from.

url.com/calendar -> click editprofile ->
it does url.com/editprofile//calendar ->  where I needed url.com/calendar

urls.py

```
path('editProfile/<str:page>/', editProfile, name='editProfile'),
```

html:

```
 {% block content %}

    <form method = "POST" action='editProfile/{{request.get_full_path}}/' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ editProfileForm.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" name="editProfileForm" value="Upload">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
@login_required
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def editProfile(request,page):
    context={}
    editProfileForm = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,instance=request.user)
    # Rework this to get url and then set nmenu to that value
    print(page)
    if page =='':
        context['nmenu']='home'
    else:
        context['nmenu']=page
    
    if editProfileForm.is_valid():
        editProfileForm.save()
        editProfileForm = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        context['editProfileForm'] = editProfileForm
        context['is_post'] = False
        return render(request, "home.html", context)
    else:
        context['is_post'] = True
        context['editProfileForm'] = editProfileForm
        return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.get_full_path` returns `/calendar`, which results in`'editProfile/' + '/calendar' = 'editProfile//calendar'`

If I got you right, you want just `'/calendar'` right? so you can reach your view as a POST request?

So then you just have to remove `editProfile/` from the form action.

Comment: I can reach my post request fine. It just uses the wrong value to redirect back to. It add /editProfile/ to wherever to redirect back to. So it ends up with Page not found.

Comment: What happens when you remove `editProfile/` from the form `action` ?

Comment: Won't run since editProfile uses that link in urls.

Comment: Yea, I am definetely not getting you! Sorry!

Comment: I just reworked it so it was included in most urls couldn't get it to work the way I wanted.